# VS Code & AWS SAM local invoke issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, docker, layer, sam

I have a serverless project on VS Code, Docker desktop 4.10 installed and I don't know why last Friday everything working fine, since Monday I got strange errors and I cant figure out. I tried to update AWS CLI, Docker, VS code and its extensions, but no progress.

This is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "configurations": [
                {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "lambda:index.handler (python3.8)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/sam-utilites/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "Services2"
            },
            "sam": {
                "containerBuild": true
            },
            "aws": {
                "credentials": "profile:default"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "python3.8",
                "payload": {
                    "path": "${workspaceFolder}/sam-utilites/events/update_item_name.json"
                },
                "environmentVariables": {
                    "TABLE_NAME": "Services2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I got this first error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
cannot import name 'winreg' from 'six.moves' (unknown location)
  File "\var\runtime\dateutil\tz\win.py", line 13, in <module> (Current frame)
    from six.moves import winreg
  File "\var\runtime\dateutil\tz\tz.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .win import tzwin, tzwinlocal
  File "\var\runtime\dateutil\tz\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .tz import *
  File "\var\runtime\botocore\compat.py", line 27, in <module>
    from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
  File "\var\runtime\botocore\configloader.py", line 19, in <module>
    from botocore.compat import six
  File "\var\runtime\botocore\session.py", line 29, in <module>
    import botocore.configloader
  File "\var\runtime\boto3\session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "\var\runtime\boto3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
```

I think something is wrong in the Docker image, or in the template file that is passing the layers to Docker.
This is my template file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Serverless Specification template describing your function.
Resources:

  AwsPowerToolsLayer:
    Properties:
      ContentUri: ../lambda-layers/aws-lambda-powertools
      LayerName: AwsPowerToolsLayer
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion

  ApiUtilities:
    Properties:
      ContentUri: ../lambda-layers/api-utilities
      LayerName: ApiUtilities
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion

  TokenUtilities:
    Properties:
      LayerName: TokenUtilities
      ContentUri: ../lambda-layers/token-utilities
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion


  Services2:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: ../lambda
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 300
      Role: >-
        arn:aws:iam::000000000000000:role/dev-0Service2ServiceRole4D3223-1MQZZZZZDEL6U
      Events:
        Api1:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /list
            Method: GET
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: tableName
      Tags:
        Environment: dev
        Application: serviceApplication
      Layers:
        - !Ref AwsPowerToolsLayer
        - !Ref ApiUtilities
        - !Ref TokenUtilities
```

Comment: EDIT:
if i call "sam local invoke -t template.yaml -e event.json" it work perfectly, but i dont have the debugger

Answer (score 0):

Have encountered this issue tonight.

See this : https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3347

In my case, I had checked "Uncaught User Exceptions" in the breakpoints. Clearing it fixed my debugger!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).